# Как вывести такой результат в GridView::widget?

Tags: php, yii2

Долго бьюсь с проблемой но так и не понял как ее решить. Есть 3 таблицы:

- список пользователей employees
- список должностей employee_positions (внешний ключ id_user к id таблицы employees и внешний ключ id_department  к id таблицы departments) - каждый пользователь имеет несколько должностей из разных подразделений
- список подразделений

Запрос к базе делаю так:

```
$dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
  'sql' => '
SELECT * FROM `employees` e
LEFT JOIN `employee_positions` p ON e.id=p.id_user
LEFT JOIN `departments` d ON d.id=p.id_department
ORDER BY e.fio ASC
',
 'totalCount' => $count,
]);
```

Во вьюхе вывожу результаты, получается, что каждый пользователь дублируется - сколько у него должностей столько и строк. А мне надо, чтобы каждый пользователь был единожды, но в правом столбце перечислялись все его должности и к какому подразделению эта должность относится. Возможно ли такое с помощью `GridView::widget`?

Пытался выводить самописную таблицу, но не понял как получить результаты из провайдера `$dataProvider`? `var_dump($dataProvider)` – не содержит самих данных.

Answer (score 0):

Получить данные текущей страницы можно так `$models = $dataProvider->getModels();` но лучше выводить все при помощи GrigView или ListView. меньше гемора.

Похоже у вас запрос выдает такие данные. В данном случае нужно смотреть в сторону вложенного запроса в котором будут должности склеиваться concat-ом и выдаваться в основной запрос.

А вообще по хорошему создать модели для таблиц с привязками. и уже в GridView получать связанные записи должностей.